# How to avoid messages from applications which I ran with a &?

Tags: command-line

I ran dolphin like this:

```
dolphin . &
```

I see messages in the console like these:

```
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
```

How can I keep the console clean or silent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can redirect the output to a file or to nowhere.

Using output redirection `>` you can redirect stdout and/or stderr away from the terminal.

To redirect stdout and stderr to a file use `&> log.txt`.

If you just want output to go way use `&> /dev/null`.

So you new command would be `dolphin . &> /dev/null &`

`&>` redirects all output

use `>` or `1>` to redirect stdout only

use `2>` to redirect stderr only

*Note:* if you want to append to a file rather than overwrite it use `>>` in place of `>`.

Comment: If one then wishes to close the terminal, it helps to also use nohup (although there are other options as well, such as screen).

Comment: @dan08 a single `&` should come at the end of the entire command.  Your examples with `&>` are incorrect.  The OP's new commands should be `dolphin . >/dev/null &` which would get rid of just standard output.  To ignore both stdout and stderr, the proper command is in Oli's reply.

Comment: I've heard it both ways

Comment: @InsomniacSoftware I would be curious as well, reference please. I am not doubting you or Oli, I would just like to educate myself.

Comment: using just `>` only redirects stdout, but Oli added an extra 2>&1 to send stderr to stdout, so both get redirected by the redirect of stdout. @InsomniacSoftware the `&>` example is correct but I was wrong about `&1>` I edited to correct

Answer (score 3):

Redirect all the output into a black hole:

```
dolphin . > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

The `2`, `1` and `0` (not used here) stand for STDERR (where all the error messages are sent), `STDOUT` (where normal output goes) and STDIN (where the input) comes from. In a normal terminal STDOUT and STDERR are both printed to screen.

The above example redirects `STDOUT` with `>` to `/dev/null` and then redirects `STDERR` into `STDOUT` so both output streams end up at `/dev/null`.